# Store a ListBox Value into a variable

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to store a selected listbox value as a variable. When I Debug `RowSelect = .List(r, 9)`. The `.List(r, 9)` returns `"10"` which is correct but `RowSelect` returns `""` Which is not correct. It should Return `"10"`. Why does the variable not Return the correct string?

This is what I have so far.

```
Dim PendClick As Boolean
Dim RrkBoxChg As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim RowSelect As String

Private Sub ListBox2_Click()
With Me.ListBox2
    If .ListIndex = -1 Then
    ElseIf .ListIndex >= 0 Then
    r = .ListIndex
        If PendClick = True Then
            Me.TextBox_Remarks = .List(r, 5)
            RowSelect = .List(r, 9)
        ElseIf PendClick = False Then
            Me.TextBox_Remarks = .List(r, 6)
            RowSelect = .List(r, 9)
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_Remarks_Change()
    r = Me.ListBox2.ListIndex
    If PendClick = True Then
        Me.ListBox2.List(r, 5) = Me.TextBox_Remarks
        Worksheets("ToolData").Cells(RowSelect, 12) = Me.TextBox_Remarks
    ElseIf PendClick = False Then
        Me.ListBox2.List(r, 6) = Me.TextBox_Remarks
        Worksheets("ToolData").Cells(RowSelect, 12) = Me.TextBox_Remarks
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The ListBox has mutiple colunms depending on if `PendClick = True` or not. I ended up finding the issue. See Answer.

Comment: You don't need to put them in the IF block, put `RowSelect = .List(r, 9)` above it.

Comment: @PatricK This is true. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue. `Me.TextBox_Remarks = .List(r, 5)` was triggering the `TextBox_Remarks_Change()` event. Which would then error out because the variable `RowSelect = ""`. I simply swaped the positions of `Me.TextBox_Remarks = .List(r, 5)` and `RowSelect = .List(r, 9)` so that the order of events was correct. This is the correction.

```
     If PendClick = True Then
        RowSelect = .List(r, 9)
        Me.TextBox_Remarks = .List(r, 5)
     ElseIf PendClick = False Then
        RowSelect = .List(r, 9)
        Me.TextBox_Remarks = .List(r, 6)
    End If
```